# How to make flexible size of UITableView during rotation

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two UITableView in UIScrollView. I am handling UIScrollView with respect of superview. Now I want to increase height of one of the TableView when screen rotate from Potrait mode to Landscape using Autolayout.

Please help me for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to make TableView's size became flexible during rotation of iPad

Comment: @AntonioMG - I nearly did. Thanks for the Headsup!